# What is difference between git checkout remotes/origin/branch and git checkout branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-detached-head

When I execute

```
git checkout remotes/origin/test_branch
```

my HEAD goes in a *detached state*. Below is output:

```
C:\..\git_test>git checkout remotes/origin/test_branch
Note: checking out 'remotes/origin/test_branch'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 4590fa2 Test branch commit
M       src/test/resources/**

C:\..\git_test>git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/test_branch)
  test_branch
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/test_branch
  remotes/origin/master
```

And if I execute

```
git checkout test_branch
```

on the same branch then I am no more in a detached state.

```
C:\..\git_test>git checkout test_branch
Switched to branch 'test_branch'
M       src/test/resources/**
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/test_branch'.

C:\..\git_test>git branch -a
* test_branch
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/test_branch
  remotes/origin/master
```

Please can anyone explain what is the difference and why it is going to the detached state while the branch is same?

Comment: Checking out a *local* branch enables tracking the branch when you commit new commits, checking out a remote tracking branch does not, and thus ends up in a detached state. Detached means "detached from a local branch".

Comment: And the branch is *not* the same. You have 2 branches, one remote and one local. There might be an upstream relationship between the two, but they *are* different. The fact that they do have the same base name does not matter. The remote branch tracks the branch in the remote repository, the local branch tracks it locally.

Comment: I like to call the `origin/*` names "remote-tracking names" these days. They don't function like branch names in your repository, as you can see ... and having the word "branch" in there encourages lines of thought that don't actually work. Try just calling them "remote-tracking names", at least mentally, to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike traditional version control systems, Git does not habitually talk to a central server. You have a complete copy of the repository and all its history. All commands are happening locally except a handful like `git pull`, `git push`, and `git fetch`.

Instead, Git keeps track of the state of remote repositories with "remote tracking branches". These are just like normal branches, except they mark the last place it saw a branch on a remote server, and you can't commit to them. These are updated when you do `git fetch` which happens as part of a `git pull`.

(One of the important things to know is that a Git "branch" is nothing more than a label pointing at a commit.)

`test_branch` is a local branch in your repository. `remotes/origin/test_branch`, usually referred to as `origin/test_branch`, is the location of a branch called `test_branch` on the remote called `origin` the last time you did a `git fetch`. If they're related, `test_branch` will have `origin/test_branch` as its upstream.

When you `git checkout test_branch` git checks out the commit `test_branch` is pointing at, moves `HEAD` to that commit (`HEAD` tracks the currently checked out commit), and marks you as being on the `test_branch`.

If you `git commit` you advance `HEAD` and `test_branch`.

```
git checkout master

              [HEAD]
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F [test_branch]

git checkout test_branch

A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F [test_branch]
                [HEAD]

git commit -a

A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G [test_branch]
                    [HEAD]
```

When you `git checkout origin/test_branch` git checks out the commit `origin/test_branch` is pointing at, moves `HEAD` to that commit (`HEAD` tracks the currently checked out commit)... and because its a remote tracking branch that's it. You are no longer on a branch, you are in a "detached HEAD" state.

If you `git commit` you advance `HEAD`, but `origin/test_branch` remains where it was.

```
git checkout master

              [HEAD]
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F [origin/test_branch]

git checkout origin/test_branch

A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F [origin/test_branch]
                [HEAD]

git commit -a

A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F [origin/test_branch]
               \
                G [HEAD]
```

With no associated branch there is nothing referring to this new commit. If you were to `git checkout master` then `G` would be dangling, effectively lost, though it can be found using [`git reflog`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_git_reflog).

```
git checkout master

              [HEAD]
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F [origin/test_branch]
               \
                G
```

See [Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) for more.

Answer (score 3):

The branch is *not* the same.

`<branch>` is your local version. An actual branch.

`remotes/origin/<branch>` is a remote-tracking branch. You don't have direct control over these, they are automatically updated upon `fetch`, they're images of the remote branches, for the sake of comparison.

You're not supposed to check these out, because committing on them or moving their position would defeat their purpose. If you do try (like you did), git does the next best thing, it checks out the commit this reference points to. Leading to a detached HEAD state.